# Crear un JSON en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo unos datos en unos arrays en Javascript y quiero recorrer esos arrays y meter los valores en un Json, estoy probado este código y no soy capaz de crear el Json. Para comprobar si lo he creado estoy tratando de imprimir un valor en

```
<span id="res"> nada</span>
```

Pero no se si estoy accediendo correctamente, no controlo mucho Javascript.

```
var arrayNombres= new Array();
var arrayApellido= new Array();
var arrayCiudad= new Array();

arrayNombres[0]= "nombre1";
arrayNombres[1]= "nombre2";
arrayNombres[2]= "nombre3";

arrayApellido[0]= "ape1 ";
arrayApellido[1]= "ape2";
arrayApellido[2]= "ape3";

arrayCiudad[0]= "ciudad1";
arrayCiudad[1]= "ciudad2";
arrayCiudad[2]= "ciudad3";

var json={datos:[{nombre :''},{apellido:''},{ciudad:''}]};
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

for (var i = 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {
     obj['datos'].push({"nombre":arrayNombres[i],"apellido":arrayApellido[i],"ciudad":arrayCiudad[i]});
};

json= JSON.stringify(obj);


$("#res").text(''+ json.datos[1].nombre);
```

La estructura que quiero que tenga el Json es

```
{
datos[
{"nombre":"", "apellidos":"", "edad":""}
{"nombre":"", "apellidos":"", "edad":""}
...
]
```

También he pensado crear un array con todos los velores que quiero en el Json y parsear esa matriz

Comment: ¿Que estructura buscas tener con el Json?  obj ->datos ->atributos

Comment: Yo estoy intentando hacer correr tu código en [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), pero no pasa nada... ¿Qué versión de JQuery estás usando, sólo para saber?

Comment: Ya añadi la estructura que pretendo tener en Json, gracias. No te sale nada porque creo que estoy creando mal el Json por eso no muestra nada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que se debe crear una estructura jerárquica y luego el objeto resultante será el valor a imprimir

```
var arrayNombres  = new Array();
var arrayApellido = new Array();
var arrayCiudad   = new Array();

arrayNombres[0] = "nombre1";
arrayNombres[1] = "nombre2";
arrayNombres[2] = "nombre3";

arrayApellido[0] = "ape1 ";
arrayApellido[1] = "ape2";
arrayApellido[2] = "ape3";

arrayCiudad[0] = "ciudad1";
arrayCiudad[1] = "ciudad2";
arrayCiudad[2] = "ciudad3";

var datos  = [];
var objeto = {};

for(var i= 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {

    var nombre = arrayNombres[i];

   datos.push({ 
        "nombre"    : arrayNombres[i],
        "apellido"  : arrayApellido[i],
        "ciudad"    : arrayCiudad[i] 
    });
}

objeto.datos = datos;
console.log(JSON.stringify(objeto));

$("#res").text(JSON.stringify(objeto));
```

Answer (score 4):

Hola el problema es que estas malinterpretando las funciones `JSON.stringify` y `JSON.parse`

Un JSON explicandolo sencillamente es un string con cierto formato, con `JSON.parse(string)` conviertes esa candena en una Objeto o Array Javascript, con 
`JSON.stringify(obj)` haces la operación inversa de convertir un Objecto javascript a un string formateado.

El problema en tu codigo es el siguiente

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

for (var i = 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {
     obj['datos'].push({"nombre":arrayNombres[i],"apellido":arrayApellido[i],"ciudad":arrayCiudad[i]});
};

json= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

la primera linea `var obj = JSON.parse(json);` no hace falta, la variable `json` es un objeto javascript no un string por lo que dará error.

por lo que el ciclo `for` quedaria asi:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {
    json['datos'].push({"nombre":arrayNombres[i],"apellido":arrayApellido[i],"ciudad":arrayCiudad[i]});
};
```

la siguiente linea `json= JSON.stringify(obj);` convierte el array a un JSON string pero generaria error en la siguiente linea , por lo que debe ser omitidad en resumen asi deberia quedar:

```
// var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for (var i = 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {
    json['datos'].push({"nombre":arrayNombres[i],"apellido":arrayApellido[i],"ciudad":arrayCiudad[i]});
};
// json= JSON.stringify(obj);
$("#res").text(''+ json.datos[1].nombre);
```

Comment: Solo un pequeño comentario, al utilizar su expresión `var json={datos:[{nombre :''},{apellido:''},{ciudad:''}]};` también generaría error, esto no lo mencionaste en tu respuesta, dado que esta mal generado el Json

Comment: Porque estaría mal, `{datos:[{nombre :''},{apellido:''},{ciudad:''}]}` siendo que esta correctamente formado el objeto javascript y al aplicarle `JSON.stringify()` devuelve el JSON string siguiente `"{"datos":[{"nombre":""},{"apellido":""},{"ciudad":""}]}"` por lo que no entiendo tu corrección.

Comment: Yo me refiero a la variable que el @silva hizo `var json={datos:[{nombre :''},{apellido:''},{ciudad:''}]};` si se deja de esta manera al hacer el Json en el ciclo `for` quedaría algo asi como `{"datos":[{"nombre":""},{"apellido":""},{"ciudad":""},{"nombre":"nombre1","apellido":"ape1 ","ciudad":"ciudad1"},{"nombre":"nombre2","apellido":"ape2","ciudad":"ciudad2"},{"nombre":"nombre3","apellido":"ape3","ciudad":"ciudad3"}]}` Slds!

Comment: Pero es que cuando accede al JSON los usa, la cantidad de  niveles depende del uso que le quiera dar quien creo el JSON es mas al final hace `$("#res").text(''+ json.datos[1].nombre);` por eso no lo modifique si quisiera mostrar el JSON completo y de manera ordenado incluso seria mejor hace `JSON.stringify(json, null, '  ')` y lo mostraria tabulado en forma de arbol.

Comment: claro, a lo que me refiero es que solo tienes que mencionar que si @silva utiliza su variable `json` tal cual, como te lo menciono en los últimos dos comentarios, el formato de salida sería el que te puse en el comentario anterior. Solo es una observación, el demás procedimiento es correcto! Slds

Answer (score 4):

La lógica que usas para hacer el push  a un objeto  `var obj = JSON.parse(json);` no es la debida lo que debes hacer es  declararla de la forma que señalo abajo. Ademas de esta hay otras formas como la de `list['datos'].push()` si lo hago así es para tener un mejor orden cuando  declares los atributos de objeto.

```js
var arrayNombres = new Array();
var arrayApellido = new Array();
var arrayCiudad = new Array();

arrayNombres[0] = "nombre1";
arrayNombres[1] = "nombre2";
arrayNombres[2] = "nombre3";

arrayApellido[0] = "ape1 ";
arrayApellido[1] = "ape2";
arrayApellido[2] = "ape3";

arrayCiudad[0] = "ciudad1";
arrayCiudad[1] = "ciudad2";
arrayCiudad[2] = "ciudad3";

// esta deberia ser la forma en la cual declaras tu objeto datos para que la pueda parsear a Json
var list = {
  'datos' :[]
};

//guardas los datos
for (var i = 0; i < arrayNombres.length; i++) {

    list.datos.push({
    "nombre": arrayNombres[i],
    "apellido": arrayApellido[i],
    "ciudad": arrayCiudad[i]
  });
};

json = JSON.stringify(list); // aqui tienes la lista de objetos en Json
var obj = JSON.parse(json); //Parsea el Json al objeto anterior.

$("#res").text('' + json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="res"> nada</span>
```