# ¿Cómo crear un json con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Hola compañeros el caso es que necesito crear un json desde jquery para después enviarlo al servidor. Tengo este formulario con los siguientes datos de código:

```js
function guardarDesripcion(ruta) {
  let codi = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
  let descrip = document.getElementById('descripcion').value;
  let unidadMedida= document.getElementById('unidadMedida').value;
  let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
  let valorUnitario = document.getElementById('valorUnitario').value;
 
  
  let json = {
    codigo: codi,
    descripcion: descrip,
    unidadMedida: unidadMedida,
    cantidad: cantidad,
    valorUnitario: valorUnitario,
  }

  console.log(json.descripcion);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-1 mb-3">
                <label for="codigo" class="titulos">Codigo <span class="tags">@FAZ02</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" id="codigo"  required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <label for="descripcion" class="titulos">Descripcion <span class="tags"> @FAZ10</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="unidadMedida" class="titulos">Unidad de Medida <span class="tags">@FAV05</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidadMedida" id="unidadMedida" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="cantidad" class="titulos">Cantidad <span class="tags">@FBB04</span></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="valorUnitario" class="titulos">Valor Unitario <span class="tags">@FBB02</span></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="valorUnitario" name="valorUnitario" required>
            </div>
            
        </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success addDescrip" onclick="guardarDesripcion()">
```

Necesito almacenar varios objetos pueden ser 1 2 o 3 o n descripciones como hago ara concatenar eso en el json

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que dices al final de la pregunta. ¿Necesitas mandar datos de varias entidades o de una sola entidad con múltiples datos en alguno de los campos como `descripcion`? El json lo puedes armar a mano como estás haciendo, en crear un array con varios json dentro, o usar  `serialize` o `serializeArray`, etc. Puedes mandar lo que quieras y como quieras según lo que necesites. Y, según lo mandes tendrás que leerlo en el servidor. Para esto te recomiendo que uses Ajax.

Comment: mira a ver si este hilo te sirve de ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150520/crear-un-json-en-javascript

Comment: método para convertir un objeto javascript a texto json: `JSON.stringify(object)`
método para convertir un texto json a objeto javascript: `JSON.parse(object)`

Answer (score 0):

Te falta ser más explícito en tu pregunta, de esta manera solo estamos tratando de adivinar cual es tu problema, pero en fin espero esto sea de tu ayuda

```
<script>
    let jsonObject = new Array();

    function guardarDesripcion(ruta) {
        let codi = document.getElementById('codigo').value;
        let descrip = document.getElementById('descripcion').value;
        let unidadMedida = document.getElementById('unidadMedida').value;
        let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
        let valorUnitario = document.getElementById('valorUnitario').value;


        jsonObject.push({
            codigo: codi,
            descripcion: descrip,
            unidadMedida: unidadMedida,
            cantidad: cantidad,
            valorUnitario: valorUnitario,
        });

        console.log(jsonObject); //array de objetos
        let jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject); //convertirmos el array de objetos a un string con formato json
        console.log(jsonString);

    }
</script>
```

1. Lo que hago es declarar un array afuera de la función para que cuando se llame dicha función no se reinicie el valor del array.
2. Cuando ejecutas la funcion **guardarDesripcion** obtienes los valores del formulario y los insertamos como objeto en el array previamente definido.
3. De esta manera podemos ir guardando todos los valores que se registren en el formulario sin perder o sobrescribir alguno.
4. Cuando quieras enviar los datos al servidor conviertes el array de objetos con **JSON.stringify()** y esto devolverá una cadena con tu datos con formato json.